# Authorize Salesforce without Username and password

Tags: api, integration, callout

I have created a connected app in SFDC.
Currently, I am using the grant_type as password with client id, client secret, username, and password to get the access token and passing that in URL,

```
https://orgurl/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=<client_Id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&username=<username>&password=<password>
```

but I am looking for a more secure and efficient way to obtain the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the client_secret, client_secret and all other data from pram tab and add them to body tab like below:

```
  const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: '<your_client_id>',
    client_secret: '<your_client_secret>',
    username: '<your_salesforce_username>',
    password: '<your_salesforce_password>'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For integrations, never use username + password. Use the "JWT Bearer Flow" Oauth. It's not standard OAuth, Salesforce co-authored a separate specification for it. It's outlined here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5

How you implement JWT Bearer Flow Oauth with your connected app depends on what programming language you're using.